# Unable to Locate email and password element on Nordstrom Website where we try and sign up

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

Following the below process:
Navigate to Nordstrom rack website and click Sign Up
When the pop up shows up enter the email and password and create account

Following is the code:

```
class EntryPoint
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String parentHandle = Driver.driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

            EmailSignUp signup = new EmailSignUp();
            Driver.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.nordstromrack.com/");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.SignUpLink.Click();
            foreach (String winHandle in Driver.driver.WindowHandles)
            {
                Driver.driver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandle);
            }

            **signup.EmailInput.Click();
            signup.EmailInput.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.BaseEmail);** //Unable to find these elements
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            **signup.Password.Click();
            signup.Password.SendKeys(Config.Credentials.Valid.Password);** //unable to locate these elements
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            signup.CreateAccount.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Driver.driver.Quit();
        }
    }
```

WebElements definition Class where the elements email and password a defined

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace NordstromRack.UI_Elements
{
    public class EmailSignUp
    {
        public EmailSignUp()
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "form-label__input form-label__input--password")]
        public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "form-label__input form-label__input--email")]
        public IWebElement EmailInput { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "secondary-nav__link")]
        public IWebElement SignUpLink { get; set; }

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "cta-button__content")]
        public IWebElement CreateAccount { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: What exact error(s) are you getting? Is it just not working? Can you show us where your WebElements are defined (eg `signup.Password`, `signup.EmailInput`), etc?

I'd say bad selectors are most likely the cause of this.

Comment: I am getting the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll
Could not find element by: By.ClassName[Contains]: form-label__input form-label__input--email. Let me add the WebElement definitions in the question

Comment: `By.ClassName` could be confused by the space in your class name.  Does the following work?

`By.CssSelector('input.form-label__input.form-label__input--email)`

Comment: Tried that and see the same error 'Could not find element by: By.CssSelector: form-label__input form-label__input--email'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the space and replace it with a dot when specifying your CSS selector.  Try replacing your top two selectors with

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-label__input.form-label__input--password")]
    public IWebElement Password { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "input.form-label__input.form-label__input--email")]
    public IWebElement EmailInput { get; set; }
```

Any better?

Comment: Well, the selectors I've provided work just fine when I use them from the dev console and when I run them in Selenium..  Are you sure you have copied them exactly?  Could you post the latest error message?

Comment: Aah wait, there was some other issue and now it works with this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear it.

Comment: Why does Class name need to be replaced with CSS selector though even though the HTML mentioned class as the identifier for this node?

Comment: When there is a space in the class name it either gets truncated or interpreted as two class names, I forget which.  Either way, using `CssSelector` and replacing the space with a dot solves the problem.

Comment: That's because there are 7 elements with the class `"cta-button__content"`

Comment: If you just use the class for the button itself that should work.  That would be 

`(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "button.cta-button.cta-button--nordstromrack")`

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will try

Comment: OKay so seem to be getting this error here. WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button type="submit" class="cta-button cta-button--secondary cta-button--nordstromrack">...</button> is not clickable at point (1239, 642). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal__overlay">...</div>

Comment: Ugh there's always something isn't there.  Looks like there is a modal overlay such that the `.click()` won't work... ever, as far as I can tell.  One thing that COULD work is pressing enter on the button, which can be done as follows:

    `signup.CreateAccount.SendKeys(Keys.Return);`

Not 100% if this will work, let me know

Comment: I actually just tried the following the error is gone but the sign up did not happen. No errors were thrown it executed beautifully but on the site the sign up was not showing. So posted another question with more details. This is what I used to remove the above error. Actions action = new Actions(Driver.driver);
            action.MoveToElement(signup.CreateAccount).Click().Perform();